# Blade Layout in Laravel is not working

Tags: laravel, laravel-blade

I have blade template namely `default.blade.php` in `app/layout/` folder

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        @include('includes.head')
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <header class="row">
                @include('includes.header')
            </header>

            <div id="main" class="row">
                @yield('content')
            </div>

            <footer class="row">
                @include('includes.footer')
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Folder structure:

```php
app/views/layout/default.blade.php
app/views/includes/footer.blade.php
app/views/includes/head.blade.php
app/views/includes/header.blade.php
```

My controller namely `blade.php`

```php
<?php
    class Blade extends BaseController
    {
        public function layout()
        {
            return View::make('layout.default');
        }
    }
?>
```

Routes.php

```php
Route::get('blade','Blade@layout');
```

I am pointing my controller in browser like:

```php
http://localhost/laravel/public/blade
```

It is showing error:

```php
Call to undefined method Illuminate\Support\Facades\Blade::getAfterFilters()
```

How can i fix it. Please help me.

Comment: `class Blade` in the root namespace is reserved in Laravel for the `Blade` alias. Change your controllers name to something a little more expressive maybe.

Comment: @David . Working Well, Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't name your Controller BLADE, Blade is a facade for the Template engine in Laravel, rename your Controller, to something else then Blade.

you can find all Laravel internal Facades in your config\app.php at the key aliases

Comment: Facades are static classes to make laravel code look better for more information look [here](http://laravel.com/docs/facades)

Comment: what are the advantages of Laravel other frameworks ?